# Error when getting the file_id of photo on Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, attributeerror, python-telegram-bot

I want to get the file_path of the photo by using telegram.exe
When I get the file_id of the document... It works 100%, but when I want to get the file_id of the photo, I cannot get the file_id : *`('list' object has no attribute 'file_id')`*

this is my function

```
def photo(update, context):
    try:
        print(update)
        obj = context.bot.getFile(file_id=update.message.photo.file_id)
        print(obj)
        #obj.download()
        update.message.reply_text("File has been downloaded")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo))
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

That's because `message.photo` is a list of `PhotoSize` objects, as documented [here](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.photo) and [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message). Since you're working with `python-telegram-bot`, let me also point you to this [wiki section](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#working-with-files-and-media) on working with files & media.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Hi @CallMeStag thanks for replying. So how to get the photo file_path ini telegrambot??

Comment: you'll have to call `get_file`